# Can i add a object inside a method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
  someFunc : function() {
    console.log("Hello");
    console.log(this);
    var obj1 = {
      someFunc1 : function() {
          console.log("Hi");
      }
    };
  }
};

obj.someFunc();
obj.obj1.someFunc1();
```

I have just created an object. And inside an object, a method, and then a new object and `obj1`. I am just trying to check `'this'` keyword. But, it seem to me it's grammatical error in js. That is not possible. Right? But, why?

Comment: it's possible, you just aren't doing it right

Comment: `this` within an object's method will refer to that object

Comment: You can use `this.obj1 = { ... }` to call `obj.obj1.someFunc1()`.

Comment: @torazaburo - Have a look [at this paste](http://pastebin.com/DmV7a3XT). `obj.obj1.someFunc1()` works perfectly.

Comment: no this is not working
var obj = {
  someFunc : function() {
    console.log("Hello");
    console.log(this);
    this.obj1 = {
      someFunc1 : function() {
          console.log(this)
      }
    };
  }
};

obj.someFunc().someFunc1();

Answer (score 2):

```
var obj = {
 someFunc : function() {
   console.log("Hello");
   console.log(this);
   return {
      someFunc1 : function() {
      console.log("Hi");
   }
  };
}
};


obj.someFunc().someFunc1();
```

Comment: What i want to know is it possible to declare another object inside a method ?? ???

var obj = {
  someFunc : function() {
    console.log(this);
   var obj1 = {
      someFunc1 : function() {
          console.log(this)
      }
    };
  }
};

obj.someFunc().someFunc1();